# In ruby on rails, how can I validate multiple attributes for a range of values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have about 10 attributes in a table that take a number as a value, for each attributes I'd like to validate whether or not a number between 1 - 100 are passed into an input. Any thoughts I can reduce the code below to a one method validation?

Currently, for each attribute, I am doing this;

`validates_numericality_of :valueone, :less_than_or_equal_to => 100`
`validates_numericality_of :valuetwo, :less_than_or_equal_to => 100`
`validates_numericality_of :valuethree, :less_than_or_equal_to => 100`

etc.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I think you should use constants. It will produce a more elegant code like so:

```
class Whatever
  MIN = 1
  MAX = 100

  validates :valueone, :valuetwo, :valuethree, :length => { :within => MIN..MAX }
end
```

You can list all attributes with the same validation as above.

This should do it. =)

Comment: Thanks Paulo. That would work as well, but more efficient way around this is what PinnyM suggested initially. Much appreciate your help and answer!

Comment: Can u explain me what is it more efficient? I didnt see the efficient part. Both do the same, the only difference is the way they do.

Comment: By efficient I meant removing attributes from within validation and placing them in an array, as in the example above. Your code is fine, but I went with PinnyM's option because I have many attributes to validate for and inline option will make it cumbersome. I hope that make sense. Thanks again.

Comment: I get the cumbersome part. But in means of eficiency they are exactly the same. The only diferencce is that in the first the iteration happens before the validation and the other inside. But i agree with the cumbersom if u have too many attributes to use. To make it even better, you could use a constant to set the attributes and iterate over it. Would be a better coding. =)

Comment: Was nothing. Im glad to help. =)

Comment: @NicholasAlek Can you select my answer as a correct one please?

Answer (score 5):

`.each` will work nicely:

```
[:valueone, :valuetwo, :valuethree, ...].each do |n|
  validates n, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 100 }
end
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks PinnyM! I'll give it a try. You are fast in responding:)

Comment: Perfectly efficient work around. I assigned a variable to iterate over collection of attributes and in doing so I reduced a lot of extraneous code for each attribute. Again, much appreciate your help PinnyM! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

validate by adding below code:

```
validates_numericality_of(
  :valueone,
  :valuetwo,
  :valuethree,
  less_than_or_equal_to: 100
)
```